# Auto-complete in RStudio works with drop_na only if drop_na is the first function

Tags: r, rstudio

I have a tibble *tb* to which I want to apply two tidyverse functions: *select* to remove two columns and *drop_na* to remove the NAs from a third column, like so:

```
tb %>% 
   select(-col1, -col2) %>%
   drop_na(col3)
```

However, Autocomplete for the column names only works in the *select* function, not in *drop_na*. If I switch the functions, Autocomplete works for *drop_na* and *select*.

```
 tb %>% 
    drop_na(col3) %>%
    select(-col1, -col2)
```

It seems therefore that *drop_na* must be the first function for Autocomplete to work. Is that a bug or a feature?

Comment: What do you mean bu autocomplete ?

Comment: Oh, sorry - I meant the RStudio feature of having the column names appear in a dropdown menu if you press Tab.

Comment: Could double check if you have still the problem because if yes autocompletion comes from Rstudio so I don't think we will find an easy answer

Comment: I do still have the problem, yes (at least I assume it's a problem and not a feature :)). It is definitely also an RStudio problem but I thought that it would at the same time be a tidyverse problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your problem because for me it works :

[image]

```
library(tidyverse)
data <- as.tibble(data.frame(X = rnorm(100),
                   Y = rnorm(100)))
data %>% 
    select(X) %>%
    drop
```

Comment: For the function it does work, but not for the column names within the function. Or does that work for you as well?