# Does RStudio's autocomplete feature have problems with dplyr's filter() function?

Tags: r, dplyr, rstudio

**Disclaimer: this is one of the cases where I would say I need to upload screenshots as I don't know how else to show the problem and what I tried to solve it, but I am not allowed to. I hope it's understandable anyway.**

I have a tibble *t* from which I would like to select four columns and then filter one of them using the *dplyr* package, like so:

```
t %>%
    select(Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4) %>%
    filter(Column3 == "XYZ")
```

RStudio's autocomplete feature works within dplyr's *select* function and recognizes all columns, i.e. when I am in the parentheses of *select* and press Tab, I get the arguments for *select* and then all the columns in *t*.

However, the autocomplete menu in dplyr's *filter* function for some reason does not recognize Column3, it only shows Column1, Column2 and Column4.

I initially thought it might have something to do with Column3 specifically, but when I tried selecting only Column1, 2 and 4, the autocomplete function no longer recognizes Column4 even though it did before, and only shows Column1 and Column2.

Column1 and Column2 are of class *double*, Column3 and Column4 are *character,* so it can't be the data type.

I tried this with several other combinations and more columns than I originally wanted to and it seems like the autocomplete feature within *filter* recognizes columns at random.

Does anyone know the reason for this? Is that a feature?

EDIT: the data set is the **LAX to JFK Sample Dataset** from here: https://developer.ibm.com/exchanges/data/all/airline/

I want to select columns *Month, DayOfWeek, Reporting_Airline*, and *CRSDepTime* and filter by column *Reporting_Airline*.

Comment: Can you share the output of running `dput(head(t))` so we can recreate the issue on our computers?

Comment: I see the same thing when I run `mtcars %>% select(mpg, cyl, gear, carb) %>% filter(<TAB HERE>)` or if I use `select` in the last line. In either case, `gear` is not offered for autocomplete. I don't know why not.

Comment: @JonSpring I added the link to the data set to the post! I thought it would be easier to use generic names. 

I tried your code and I get the same problem - gear is not recognized by autocomplete. Thank you very much, at least I know now it's not my fault :)

Comment: I have entered an issue to dplyr: https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/6629

Comment: Wonderful, thank you so much!

Actually I think there might be a general problem with autocomplete and dplyr, I had the same issue with drop_na:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72295943/auto-complete-in-rstudio-works-with-drop-na-only-if-drop-na-is-the-first-functio

Comment: Aha, I guess this is an RStudio Desktop issue then. https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/12501

Comment: Thank you so much for your help on this, I wouldn't have known how to enter an issue on github!